# Why can't DFT calculate the energy of magnetic diatomic molecules accurately?

Tags: density-functional-theory, molecular-modeling, magnetism

I am trying to calculate the reaction enthalpy change of $\ce{2H2 + O2->2H2O}$, my plan is to calculate the energy of $\ce{H2, O2 \text{and} H2O}$, respectively, then do the simple math.

But I find some papers don't do it this way: They calculate the energy of $\ce{H2}$, $\ce{H2O}$, look up the reaction enthalpy change from an experimental database, then calculate the energy of $\ce{O2}$, because DFT couldn't calculate the energy of magnetic diatomic molecules accurately.

My question is:
Why must the energy be calculated this way (or what is wrong with DFT in this case)?

Comment: Can you point to some of these paper?  It's not clear what you mean by magnetic molecules in this context.

Comment: Due to paramagnetism of oxygen, you have to execute an un-restricted spin DFT, uncomparable with the restricted DFT for $\ce{H2}$ end $\ce{H2O}$

Comment: @AndreaPellegrini， Could I do un-restricted spin DFT in VASP? Currently, I am using `ISPIN=2`, does this mean I am doing un-restricted spin DFT?

Comment: @Jack Running O2 calculations in DFT is hopeless, you need to signify triplet oxygen but even if you run the calculation it is a random number generator.  Try different functionals and see how the dissociation energy of O2 is wildly different.

Comment: Possibly related question on Chem SE: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6709/why-is-density-functional-theory-notoriously-bad-at-describing-oxygen-molecules

Comment: @AndreaPellegrini No, you can compare the results of restricted DFT with those of unrestricted DFT. The reason is (1) you can perform unrestricted DFT calculations even if the system is spin-paired, and the results are undoubtedly comparable with unrestricted DFT results of oxygen; and (2) when the system is spin-paired, it is mathematically guaranteed that a restricted DFT calculation yields exactly the same result as an unrestricted DFT calculation. When a discrepancy of the level of theory is mathematically guaranteed to not alter the result, the discrepancy does not hamper comparability.

Comment: @wzkchem5 this question seems simple enough to answer though, do you think you can write an answer to the question of why DFT is not expected to work well for O2? The OP mentions that papers have used DFT for H2 and H2O, then they looked up experimental information about the 2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O reaction in order to deduce the energy of O2 (hence avoiding DFT for O2). Jack, why would you use VASP for calculations on small polyatomic molecules? VASP is mainly a plane-wave code, and there's better methods/software for dealing with small polyatomics.